# Fscanf Not Reading Both Integers and Characters

Tags: c, scanf

I'm working with the following code below. For a file with content "1 + 1", this code should output "1 + 1". However, it outputs "1 _ 1" where '_' is a whitespace character. I'm not sure where this problem is coming from and why my character is either not being read or not being output properly. My code obviously works just fine if I'm reading two integers. Any pointers in the right direction (no pun intended)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  FILE *in_file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // read only 
  int input_num_1;
  char operation;
  int input_num_2;
  fscanf(in_file, "%d%c%d", &input_num_1, &operation, &input_num_2);
  printf("%d %c %d\n", input_num_1, operation, input_num_1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change it to `"%d %c%d"`.  `%c` is picking up the space between the `1` and the `+`.

Comment: That identifies the problem, but it's a pretty horrible solution

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you!

Comment: The `scanf` functions are notoriously bad for validating user input that is of any complexity.

Comment: Somebody please make an answer or come up with a dupe or another close reason...

Comment: supersmarty1234, Tip: When `*scanf(...)` functions do not work as expected, the first thing to do is check the result as in `if (fscanf(in_file, "%d%c%d", &input_num_1, &operation, &input_num_2) == 3) Success(); else Fail();`.

Comment: @supersmarty1234 Another thing: You probably figured this out, but you've got `input_num_1` twice in your last `printf` call.

Comment: Although the extra space is not necessary, the code looks a bit cleaner (IMO) if you use the format string `"%d %c %d"`